# Java Serialization issue JSON Array

Tags: java, json, serialization

My local machine has the java version 1.8.0_11 and the server has java version 1.8.0_45.

See the way the object is serialized in the two machines.

The below result is on the server machine. Please see the **to** array.

```
{
  "message": {
    "view_content_link": false,
    "headers": {

    },
    "metadata": {

    },
    "images": [

    ],
    "from_email": "atr@in.com",
    "attachments": [

    ],
    "subject": "Test email for 123 123 from local with jar",
    "recipient_metadata": [

    ],
    "track_opens": false,
    "preserve_recipients": false,
    "from_name": "IT",
    "tags": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "important": false,
    "async": true,
    "merge": true,
    "auto_text": false,
    "inline_css": false,
    "html": "<h3>test mail<\/h3>",
    "text": "text",
    "to": [
      {
        "name": "ABC",
        "type": "to",
        "email": "atr@it.com"
      }
    ],
    "auto_html": false,
    "track_clicks": false,
    "url_strip_qs": false
  },
  "key": "adsfadfasdfaf"
}
```

The below result is on my local machine. Please see the to array.

```
{
  "message": {
    "view_content_link": false,
    "headers": {

    },
    "metadata": {

    },
    "images": [

    ],
    "from_email": "it@in.com",
    "attachments": [

    ],
    "subject": "Test email for 123 123 from local with jar",
    "recipient_metadata": [

    ],
    "track_opens": false,
    "preserve_recipients": false,
    "from_name": "IT",
    "tags": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "important": false,
    "async": true,
    "merge": true,
    "auto_text": false,
    "inline_css": false,
    "html": "<h3>test mail<\/h3>",
    "text": "text",
    "to": [
      "{\"name\": \"ABC\", \"type\": \"to\", \"email\": \"atr@it.com\"}"
    ],
    "auto_html": false,
    "track_clicks": false,
    "url_strip_qs": false
  },
  "key": "adsfadfasdfaf"
}
```

Code is

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Recipient implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4757902777678958032L;
    private String email;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email
     *            the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * @param type
     *            the type to set
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String toString() {
         return "{\"name\": \"" + name + "\", \"type\": \"" + type + "\", \"email\": \"" + email + "\"}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, what is your problem exactly? it seems that toSringMethod overrides json serialization. is it it?

Comment: what library and version are you using to achieve JSON serialization?

Comment: Look at the way how the receipient data has been serialized. You can see the problem.